# Использование AES-256-GCM в C

Tags: c, криптография, aes

Мне нужно шифровать сообщение AES-256-GCM в C без использования крупных библиотек.

Единственное что нашел - [Tiny AES](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c), но там нет поддержки GCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [Раз](https://github.com/theicfire/aes-gcm)

2) [Два](https://github.com/Shay-Gueron/AES-GCM-SIV)

3) [Три](https://github.com/michaeljclark/aes-gcm)

Исходники из 3-го:

```
/*
 * Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) and GMAC with AES
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi>
 *
 * This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
 * See README for more details.
 */

#include "aes.h"

static void inc32(aes_uchar *block)
{
    aes_uint val;
    val = AES_GET_BE32(block + AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 4);
    val++;
    AES_PUT_BE32(block + AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 4, val);
}


static void xor_block(aes_uchar *dst, const aes_uchar *src)
{
    aes_uint *d = (aes_uint *) dst;
    aes_uint *s = (aes_uint *) src;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
}


static void shift_right_block(aes_uchar *v)
{
    aes_uint val;

    val = AES_GET_BE32(v + 12);
    val >>= 1;
    if (v[11] & 0x01)
        val |= 0x80000000;
    AES_PUT_BE32(v + 12, val);

    val = AES_GET_BE32(v + 8);
    val >>= 1;
    if (v[7] & 0x01)
        val |= 0x80000000;
    AES_PUT_BE32(v + 8, val);

    val = AES_GET_BE32(v + 4);
    val >>= 1;
    if (v[3] & 0x01)
        val |= 0x80000000;
    AES_PUT_BE32(v + 4, val);

    val = AES_GET_BE32(v);
    val >>= 1;
    AES_PUT_BE32(v, val);
}


/* Multiplication in GF(2^128) */
static void gf_mult(const aes_uchar *x, const aes_uchar *y, aes_uchar *z)
{
    aes_uchar v[16];
    int i, j;

    memset(z, 0, 16); /* Z_0 = 0^128 */
    memcpy(v, y, 16); /* V_0 = Y */

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (x[i] & 1 << (7 - j)) {
                /* Z_(i + 1) = Z_i XOR V_i */
                xor_block(z, v);
            } else {
                /* Z_(i + 1) = Z_i */
            }

            if (v[15] & 0x01) {
                /* V_(i + 1) = (V_i >> 1) XOR R */
                shift_right_block(v);
                /* R = 11100001 || 0^120 */
                v[0] ^= 0xe1;
            } else {
                /* V_(i + 1) = V_i >> 1 */
                shift_right_block(v);
            }
        }
    }
}


static void ghash_start(aes_uchar *y)
{
    /* Y_0 = 0^128 */
    memset(y, 0, 16);
}


static void ghash(const aes_uchar *h, const aes_uchar *x, size_t xlen, aes_uchar *y)
{
    size_t m, i;
    const aes_uchar *xpos = x;
    aes_uchar tmp[16];

    m = xlen / 16;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        /* Y_i = (Y^(i-1) XOR X_i) dot H */
        xor_block(y, xpos);
        xpos += 16;

        /* dot operation:
         * multiplication operation for binary Galois (finite) field of
         * 2^128 elements */
        gf_mult(y, h, tmp);
        memcpy(y, tmp, 16);
    }

    if (x + xlen > xpos) {
        /* Add zero padded last block */
        size_t last = x + xlen - xpos;
        memcpy(tmp, xpos, last);
        memset(tmp + last, 0, sizeof(tmp) - last);

        /* Y_i = (Y^(i-1) XOR X_i) dot H */
        xor_block(y, tmp);

        /* dot operation:
         * multiplication operation for binary Galois (finite) field of
         * 2^128 elements */
        gf_mult(y, h, tmp);
        memcpy(y, tmp, 16);
    }

    /* Return Y_m */
}


static void aes_gctr(void *aes, const aes_uchar *icb, const aes_uchar *x, size_t xlen, aes_uchar *y)
{
    size_t i, n, last;
    aes_uchar cb[AES_BLOCK_SIZE], tmp[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    const aes_uchar *xpos = x;
    aes_uchar *ypos = y;

    if (xlen == 0)
        return;

    n = xlen / 16;

    memcpy(cb, icb, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    /* Full blocks */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        aes_encrypt(aes, cb, ypos);
        xor_block(ypos, xpos);
        xpos += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
        ypos += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
        inc32(cb);
    }

    last = x + xlen - xpos;
    if (last) {
        /* Last, partial block */
        aes_encrypt(aes, cb, tmp);
        for (i = 0; i < last; i++)
            *ypos++ = *xpos++ ^ tmp[i];
    }
}


static void * aes_gcm_init_hash_subkey(const aes_uchar *key, size_t key_len, aes_uchar *H)
{
    void *aes;

    aes = aes_encrypt_init(key, key_len);
    if (aes == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Generate hash subkey H = AES_K(0^128) */
    memset(H, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    aes_encrypt(aes, H, H);
    aes_hexdump_key(MSG_EXCESSIVE, "Hash subkey H for GHASH", H, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    return aes;
}


static void aes_gcm_prepare_j0(const aes_uchar *iv, size_t iv_len, const aes_uchar *H, aes_uchar *J0)
{
    aes_uchar len_buf[16];

    if (iv_len == 12) {
        /* Prepare block J_0 = IV || 0^31 || 1 [len(IV) = 96] */
        memcpy(J0, iv, iv_len);
        memset(J0 + iv_len, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE - iv_len);
        J0[AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 1] = 0x01;
    } else {
        /*
         * s = 128 * ceil(len(IV)/128) - len(IV)
         * J_0 = GHASH_H(IV || 0^(s+64) || [len(IV)]_64)
         */
        ghash_start(J0);
        ghash(H, iv, iv_len, J0);
        AES_PUT_BE64(len_buf, 0);
        AES_PUT_BE64(len_buf + 8, iv_len * 8);
        ghash(H, len_buf, sizeof(len_buf), J0);
    }
}


static void aes_gcm_gctr(void *aes, const aes_uchar *J0, const aes_uchar *in, size_t len,
             aes_uchar *out)
{
    aes_uchar J0inc[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

    if (len == 0)
        return;

    memcpy(J0inc, J0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    inc32(J0inc);
    aes_gctr(aes, J0inc, in, len, out);
}


static void aes_gcm_ghash(const aes_uchar *H, const aes_uchar *aad, size_t aad_len,
              const aes_uchar *crypt, size_t crypt_len, aes_uchar *S)
{
    aes_uchar len_buf[16];

    /*
     * u = 128 * ceil[len(C)/128] - len(C)
     * v = 128 * ceil[len(A)/128] - len(A)
     * S = GHASH_H(A || 0^v || C || 0^u || [len(A)]64 || [len(C)]64)
     * (i.e., zero padded to block size A || C and lengths of each in bits)
     */
    ghash_start(S);
    ghash(H, aad, aad_len, S);
    ghash(H, crypt, crypt_len, S);
    AES_PUT_BE64(len_buf, aad_len * 8);
    AES_PUT_BE64(len_buf + 8, crypt_len * 8);
    ghash(H, len_buf, sizeof(len_buf), S);

    aes_hexdump_key(MSG_EXCESSIVE, "S = GHASH_H(...)", S, 16);
}


/**
 * aes_gcm_ae - GCM-AE_K(IV, P, A)
 */
int aes_gcm_ae(const aes_uchar *key, size_t key_len, const aes_uchar *iv, size_t iv_len,
           const aes_uchar *plain, size_t plain_len,
           const aes_uchar *aad, size_t aad_len, aes_uchar *crypt, aes_uchar *tag)
{
    aes_uchar H[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    aes_uchar J0[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    aes_uchar S[16];
    void *aes;

    aes = aes_gcm_init_hash_subkey(key, key_len, H);
    if (aes == NULL)
        return -1;

    aes_gcm_prepare_j0(iv, iv_len, H, J0);

    /* C = GCTR_K(inc_32(J_0), P) */
    aes_gcm_gctr(aes, J0, plain, plain_len, crypt);

    aes_gcm_ghash(H, aad, aad_len, crypt, plain_len, S);

    /* T = MSB_t(GCTR_K(J_0, S)) */
    aes_gctr(aes, J0, S, sizeof(S), tag);

    /* Return (C, T) */

    aes_encrypt_deinit(aes);

    return 0;
}


/**
 * aes_gcm_ad - GCM-AD_K(IV, C, A, T)
 */
int aes_gcm_ad(const aes_uchar *key, size_t key_len, const aes_uchar *iv, size_t iv_len,
           const aes_uchar *crypt, size_t crypt_len,
           const aes_uchar *aad, size_t aad_len, const aes_uchar *tag, aes_uchar *plain)
{
    aes_uchar H[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    aes_uchar J0[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    aes_uchar S[16], T[16];
    void *aes;

    aes = aes_gcm_init_hash_subkey(key, key_len, H);
    if (aes == NULL)
        return -1;

    aes_gcm_prepare_j0(iv, iv_len, H, J0);

    /* P = GCTR_K(inc_32(J_0), C) */
    aes_gcm_gctr(aes, J0, crypt, crypt_len, plain);

    aes_gcm_ghash(H, aad, aad_len, crypt, crypt_len, S);

    /* T' = MSB_t(GCTR_K(J_0, S)) */
    aes_gctr(aes, J0, S, sizeof(S), T);

    aes_encrypt_deinit(aes);

    if (memcmp(tag, T, 16) != 0) {
        aes_printf(MSG_EXCESSIVE, "GCM: Tag mismatch");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int aes_gmac(const aes_uchar *key, size_t key_len, const aes_uchar *iv, size_t iv_len,
         const aes_uchar *aad, size_t aad_len, aes_uchar *tag)
{
    return aes_gcm_ae(key, key_len, iv, iv_len, NULL, 0, aad, aad_len, NULL, tag);
}
```

Ну и т.д.

Comment: А есть примеры использования?

Например у меня есть массив с ключом - my_key, и массив с текстом - my_text.

Тоже самое для дешифрации

Comment: Ну вы совесть то имейте... У вас есть исходники, есть примеры в исходниках, есть голова на плечах :)